# Replace an HTML element with some HTML contained in a string

Tags: javascript, html, xml-parsing

Let's say I have this portion of HTML document:

```
<div>hello world <span id="test"></span></div>
```

In straight JavaScript, I need to replace the `span` with some HTML content contained in a string like *`'<span>other</span> yo <a href="www.google.ca">google</a>'`*

So the end result be like:

```
<div>hello world <span>other</span> yo <a href="www.google.ca">google</a></div>
```

The problem I'm facing is that the HTML string can contain any number of tags at its "root". So it is not a 1 to 1 replacement of tags.

I need to do that in straight JavaScript (no jQuery).

If anyone can help!

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What is the reason you can't just set the innerHTML  of `<span id="test">`? There's no harm in having the extra span...

If you really need to remove the outer span, you can just insert all the childNodes before it.

```
var html = '<span>other</span> yo <a href="www.google.ca">google</a>';

var removeMe = document.getElementById('test');
removeMe.innerHTML = html;

var child;
while(child = removeMe.childNodes[0]) {
    removeMe.parentNode.insertBefore(child, removeMe);
}

removeMe.parentNode.removeChild(removeMe);
```

See http://jsfiddle.net/4tLVC/1/

Comment: I actually used your technique, but instead of working inside "removeMe", I created an unattached 'div' element and inserted the content into it, it might be a little faster since the dom objects are not attached to the main document.. But thank you very much it solved my problem :)

Comment: I am finally using this code: it seems I was loosing the ' yo ' text node with yours... http://jsfiddle.net/4zMha/ But thanks again!

Comment: Ahh, the bug is that i increases but the node is removed from the list, so it gets skipped, fixed the code and the jsfiddle

Answer (score 0):

can't you use

```
 var span = document.getElement...('test')
 div.getElementById('yourDiv').removeChild(span)
```

or actually you can do

```
span.parentNode.removeChild(span)
```

this should work to.
After that

```
 div.innerHTML += 'your cool <span>content></span>'
```

Comment: apparently someone does not like me ;-)